# Summing the heights of every simple non-left-moving paths $(0,0)\to (n,m)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a challenging question assigned regarding Counting. here is the question:

> Consider a square lattice $(\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^2)$ with point $A$ on its bottom left (the origin) and point $B$ on its top right. We call a path from $A$ to $B$ a **good** path if it does not ever move left and it does not visit any point more than once. For each *good* path, we write down the height (the $y$-coordinate) of every horizontal segment. What is the sum of the numbers written down?

I have attached an example picture. In this case, the sum is $1+3+0+0+0+5+1=10$.

[image: an instance of a good path]

At first, I had the idea of solving the same problem for a smaller instance but still could not find the general approach to it. I think this is, in core, a stars and bars problem since we have to have $7$ moves to right and the fact that the number of squares is actually related to the number of moves we take to the right. I have also noticed that we have to take $5$ upward steps more than downward steps so that we can get to the point B. I'd appreciate it if you could help me find the idea for this case and the general $n\times m$ case.

Comment: "not crossed the same line more than once". Could you please explain what you mean be that? The line can be crossed exactly one time? And if so, how? For example am I allowed to go up and then go down during the subsequent move?

Comment: I would say that, if we are not allowed to go up and then down (or vice versa) on the same vertical line, the problem seems fairly straight forward. This is not stars and bars, rather consider permutations with repetition. For example you can write the path in your graph as (1,3,0,0,0,5,1). Of course, if we are allowed to go up-down or down-up on the same vertical line then we are creating additional paths to consider, and the problem becomes more complicated.

Comment: I think you can easily show that every possible set of heights of the columns beneath the curve ($\in \{1,..., n\}^m$) can all be achieved and exactly once. Then the summation is simple.

Comment: @tps you're intuition is correct. the same line cannot be passed more than once. but about the permutations with repetitions that you mentioned; how does this apply to the number of squares? I believe this approach would help for the number of paths and not the squares below the path( the blue squares shown in the picture)

Comment: @caduk I think I'm not exactly followling your method. could you please elaborate?

Comment: As tps mentioned, you can represent your example path by a vector $(1,3,0,0,0,5,1)$. What set of vectors can be represented by a good path? Can the same vector represent two distinct good paths?

Comment: @caduk I believe not. paths will be unique but they can have the same number of squares below themselves

Comment: I don't talk about the total number of squares below, only about the number of squares below by columns. Is there another path represented by the vector $(1,3,0,0,0,5,1)$?

Comment: @caduk Oh, I see your point now. so what I have to do is to actually find the occurrence of each possible arrangement in this model vector and get the final sum?

Comment: @itspaspas yes, that would do it. What answer do  you get this way?

Comment: @DS  well now that I look into it I see it's more complicated than what it looks. what comes right into mind is to calculate all the possible sums with numbers from zero to five and then multiply each possible sum by its possible arrangements of the squares in each column but is there a simpler and more creative way to find the solution?

Comment: This is simple and creative enough. You should get $105 \cdot 6^6$ easily.

Comment: @itspaspas There is a much simpler solution. the sum can be written as $\sum_{x_1=0}^5...\sum_{x_6=0}^5 (x_1 + x_2+ ... + x_6)$. You should be able to easily compute this kind of summation and get a nice formula for all $m$ and $n$ (and you should find $15\cdot 6^6$, not $105\cdot 6^6$).

Comment: Another way (not particularly nicer) is to count the number of times a cell is counted (depending on its height)

Comment: @caduk Dear caduk, Does this second method you mentioned have to do anything with the stars and bars with an upper bound limit? because what has been bothering me with this calculation is that it gets really over the top. I believe the first method that you suggested is more elegant. also, thanks for your great insight!

Comment: @caduk also I believe D S was right for 105 and not 15 because we have 7 columns. feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I appreciate both of you again.

Comment: Ah yeah there is $7$ columns, so you need to correct it in my comment too. Nothing to do with stars and bars, there is no binomial coefficients involved here. You just need to see that each configuration for a column appears (with $n$ columns of height $m$) $m+1$ times for each other column (so $(m+1)^{n-1}$). Then depending on the height, we can compute how many times a cell appear. This is very similar to the simplification of the sum, just another point of view.

Comment: please revert if my edit is a misunderstanding. But the question read vague as stated.

Comment: @caduk next time please answer in an actual answer. Comments cannot be easily viewed nor voted on, and can be difficult to change in case of errors.

Comment: @DS next time please answer in an actual answer. Comments cannot be easily viewed nor voted on, and can be difficult to change in case of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(n,m)$.

The heights in each good path can be represented by a string $(x_1,\dots, x_{n})$ where each height is in $\{0,\dots,m\}$. All such strings represent good paths. So there are $(m+1)^n$ good paths.

The average height is $m/2$. There are $n$ heights in each path. So the sum is

$$\frac12 mn(m+1)^n.$$

You can show that taking the average works by a bijection argument, i.e. pairing each path with its "opposite-height" path (for even $m$ the path with no pair occurs once and is exactly average-height).